# How do I create a vertical jQuery or CSS slider for an inline element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So basically I saw this really cool CSS animation on code pen (https://codepen.io/yoannhel/pen/sJpDj) and I've been trying to replicate it so that it would work for me.  I was able to replicate the animation on the brackets with CSS fairly easily, but I have absolutely no idea how to do the transition between changing text like they did.  I want to replicate the way that new text slides down into the visible inline view frame and then slides out.

I would prefer if this had a CSS only solution but at this point I'll take anything.

This is the code I have so far

```js
var users = ["bob", "john", "world", "everyone"];
counter = 0;
setInterval(function() {
  //slide down off screen

  //Change Value
  if (counter >= (users.length - 1)) {
    elUser.textContent = users[counter];
    counter = 0;
  } else {
    elUser.textContent = users[counter];
    counter += 1
  }

  //reset to top
  $("#user").animate({
    bottom: '-=120'
  });

  //slide down on screen
}, 2000);
```

```css
@keyframes WelcomeBrackets {
  0% {
    color: rgba(242, 12, 54, 0);
  }
  50% {
    color: rgba(242, 12, 54, 1);
  }
  100% {
    color: rgba(242, 12, 54, 0);
  }
}

#user {
  display: inline;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.bracket {
  animation: WelcomeBrackets 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  color: #2603c1;
}
```

```html
<h1><span class="bracket">[ </span> Welcome <span id="user">User</span>
  <span class="bracket"> ]</span>
</h1>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not call the correct id. change your Div ID as **elUser** and it will work.

```js
var users = ["bob", "john", "world", "everyone"];
counter = 0;
setInterval(function() {
  //slide down off screen

  //Change Value
  if (counter >= (users.length - 1)) {
    elUser.textContent = users[counter];
    counter = 0;
  } else {
    elUser.textContent = users[counter];
    counter += 1
  }

  //reset to top
  $("#user").animate({
    bottom: '-=120'
  });

  //slide down on screen
}, 2000);
```

```css
@keyframes WelcomeBrackets {
  0% {
    color: rgba(242, 12, 54, 0);
  }
  50% {
    color: rgba(242, 12, 54, 1);
  }
  100% {
    color: rgba(242, 12, 54, 0);
  }
}

#user {
  display: inline;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.bracket {
  animation: WelcomeBrackets 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  color: #2603c1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1><span class="bracket">[ </span> Welcome <span id="elUser">User</span>
  <span class="bracket"> ]</span>
</h1>
```

You can get the output using **Slide Up** and **Slide Down** animation.
To get the knowledge on that please refer the snippet below

```css
@keyframes WelcomeBrackets {
  0% {
    color: rgba(242, 12, 54, 0);
  }
  50% {
    color: rgba(242, 12, 54, 1);
  }
  100% {
    color: rgba(242, 12, 54, 0);
  }
}

#user {
  display: inline;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.bracket {
  animation: WelcomeBrackets 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  color: #2603c1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1><span class="bracket">[ </span> Welcome <span id="elUser">User</span>
  <span class="bracket"> ]</span>
</h1>

<script>
       
        var users = ["bob", "john", "world", "everyone"];
        counter = 0;
        setInterval(function () {
  
            $('#elUser').slideDown(1000);
          
            if (counter >= (users.length - 1)) {
                elUser.textContent = users[counter];
                $('#elUserelUser').slideDown(1000);
                counter = 0;
            } else {
                elUser.textContent = users[counter];
                $('#elUser').slideUp(1000);
                counter += 1;
            }

        }, 2000);
       
</script>
```